# ASP NET Boilerplate API project creation problem

Tags: aspnetboilerplate

It is a first time that I am using ASP.NET Boilerplate for API development. There are default features like  multi tenancy and role management which I don’t want to use in the template. When creating a new project. in the project wizard I am choosing “Single Page Web Application” and I am unchecking the “Include login, register, user, role and tenant management pages” box. But when I do this, it is removing the connection between Swagger and Application Service. So the methods I am writing in Application Service are not being translated as API endpoints automatically.

Ideally, I want this: ABP Template + Empty API solution + swagger connection.

Am I missing something? Could you point me in the right direction? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

"The methods that I am writing in the Application Service are not automatically translated as API endpoints." Regarding that, the app service should be translated automatically in the version that does not include login and roles, check the documentation. Regarding the swagger, you have to add it manually.